# How to remove unique id in firebase Realtime database using Xamarin

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

I'm new in Xamarin but i don't need this unique key. how i can remove this?

[image]

please help me to remove this unique key, this is the code. thank you.

```
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Database.Query;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RealTimeIot
{
    internal class StudentRepository
    {
        FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("https://student-part-ca785-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/");

        public async Task<bool> Save(StudentModel student)
        {

            var data = await firebaseClient.Child("User").PostAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student));

            //var data = await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(StudentModel)).PostAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Key))
            {
               return true;
            }
           return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the data that i want to add

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace RealTimeIot
{
    public class StudentModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you `POST` data to a path in the Realtime Database, Firebase generates a new unique key under that path for the data.

If you want to write the data directly to the path use `PUT`, which in your client corresponds to `PutAsync`.

Comment: Hello sir can i get example code of PutAsync? Thank you for the response.

Comment: It's the same as `PostAsync` as far as I know, so `firebaseClient.Child("User").PutAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student))` should do the trick. If that doesn't work, edit your question to show what you tried and what result you got.